# undefined reference to __atomic_store_16

Tags: c++, atomic

Следующий код, который имеет в себе использование 16 байтной атомарной переменной

```
#include <atomic>

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

int main() {
    std::atomic<A> a;
    a.store(A{1,2,3,4});
}
```

компилируется командой

```
g++ -latomic -O0 main.cpp
```

в результате получается вывод

```
/tmp/ccUracLg.o: In function `std::atomic<A>::store(A, std::memory_order)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6atomicI1AE5storeES0_St12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicI1AE5storeES0_St12memory_order]+0x62): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Вопрос в том как правильно подключить libatomic? Система mint 19 64bit, компилятор gcc-9.

Comment: Попробуйте переставить `-latomic` в конец команды.

Comment: спасибо, работает :) А с чем это связано?

Comment: Это особенность многих линковщиков (например LD), подробнее вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc